# Aforge.net consuming lot of CPU power

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

I'm running Aforge.net's provided two camera test samples on my Dual Core 2.0 GHz laptop with 2 GB RAM. Right now I'm seeing a lot of CPU usage as the application starts displaying visuals from 2 cameras. It's currently consuming 60% to 70% of the entire CPU power. Can anyone tell me why it's consuming that much CPU and how can I avoid it as I have to build a similar application which would require 2 camera vision and I would be using C#.

Comment: How much data is generated by the cameras pr. sec? I was amazed how much data a Kinect-cam generates. Have you tried profiling your app to see where/how the time is spent?

Comment: Hi I am also facing same problem CPU   consuming 60% to 70%. Have you got solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a lot of things. Turn on a profiler and find out where the time is spent. Then adjust your question!

Comment: Profiling didn't helped as well. This problem is also on aforge forum but apparently no resolution. All it says is to blame microsoft for creating WMV3 codec which requires compression which in turn is increasing CPU usage.

Comment: Maybe you can get the cameras to stream in another format so you do not use the WMV3 code?